# Is it possible to add stylesheet to JavaFX Scene from remote css file?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, stylesheet

I tried to add external style sheet to my `JavaFX` application.

Example:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("http://localhost/css/style.css");
```

But it didn't work, so is there any way to load the css file from external resource , and add its contents to the scene css classes ? or add its css file to scene style sheet files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is reasonable that JavaFX users would think it possible to do this. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) does specify that the add method takes a URL as a string.

> Beginning with JavaFX 2.1, the Parent class has a stylesheets
>   property, allowing style sheets to be set on a container. This allows
>   for one branch of of the scene graph to have a distinct set of styles.
>   Any instance of Parent can have a style sheets. A child will take its
>   styles from its own inline styles, the style sheets of all its
>   ancestors, and any style sheets from the Scene.
>
> A style sheet URL may be an absolute URL or a relative URL. If a
>   relative URL is given, it is resolved against the base URL of the
>   ClassLoader of the concrete Application class. If, for example, there
>   is a main class com.wicked.cool.ui.Main that extends Application, the
>   relative URL "com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css" would resolve
>   correctly. The relative URL "../resources/styles.css" would not since
>   the path ".." relative to the root is not a valid path. It is often
>   easier to use the ClassLoader of some class to find the resource. For
>   example, if the "styles.css" file resides in the same package as Main,
>   the following code will give the correct URL:
>   com.wicked.cool.ui.Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm()
>
> Note that, beginning with JavaFX 2.1, a URL consisting of only an
>   absolute path (having no scheme or authority) is resolved relative to
>   the base URL of ClassLoader of the class that extends Application. In
>   other words, "/com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css" is treated as
>   "com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css". This is consistent with FXML.
>   The implementation allows designers to style an application by using
>   style sheets to override property values set from code. This has
>   implications for the cascade; particularly, when does a style from a
>   style sheet override a value set from code? The JavaFX CSS
>   implementation applies the following order of precedence; a style from
>   a user agent style sheet has lower priority than a value set from
>   code, which has lower priority than a Scene or Parent style sheet.
>   Inline styles have highest precedence. Style sheets from a Parent
>   instance are considered to be more specific than those styles from
>   Scene style sheets.

The documentation talks about absolute and relative URLs in relationship to the class loader though. So, if using a URL that points to some resource on the internet does not work I think the best thing you could do is file a bug report. Either a URL pointing to a resource on the internet should work, or the documentation should explicitly specify that only local resources (local to the classloader) are valid.

Comment: it worked after i added ".css" to the style file name in the URL , i didn't add the .css extension before ..